# Distributing a Google play private apps

Tags: google-play, google-admin-sdk, google-play-console

I have an app that i am developing that i need to deploy to only persons of my choosing. I don't want it to be available on the play store to the public. I simply want to make it available to selected persons. Is this possible with google play console?
I have tried doing it with Google play private app distribution but this seems to be a way in which companies can distribute apps to their employees. Such that the user would have to join the organisation. I don't want this type of distribution. I just want to be able to allow specific persons to download the app from the play store similar to how it works in closed testing.

Is this possible with Google play store console ?

Comment: a code based strategy works fine ( anyone can download but only with certain code can use the app once launched )

Comment: @AmodGokhale what do you mean by a "code based strategy" are you referring to the command line version where user can upload apps ?

Comment: provide a code ( example 2954829 ) to specific users. You code should able to process users only with a valid code.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use closed testing and add the people you want to download the app into the channel using their email addresses.

Comment: is that really the only way ?

Comment: Either that or Managed Google Play.